# Update method in JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextfield, twitter4j

I'm creating a Twitter client in Java with Twitter4j. My intention is to make a count that tells you how many characters are remaining for your tweet. It would start with 140 and with every character I wrote it would be updated. I have been thinking a bit and it would be something like this:

```
int count = 140;
count = count - textField.getText().length();
chCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
```

The problem is that I don't know how to update run that code constantly. I have tried with the update() method but it isn't being called

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you by "runs constantly" - Swing is [event driven](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#addDocumentListener(javax.swing.event.DocumentListener)). Multithreading is completely the wrong approach, look elsewhere.

Comment: But I need to change the count everytime I type anything on the Text Field

Comment: Did you even bother to read the link?

Comment: Yes, I can't add a document listener to the TextField, I will try with keylistener/actionlistener thanks

Comment: Again, did you bother to read the link? What's wrong with [`JTextField.getDocuemnt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument())?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see getDocument, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach a document listener to the document of the text field, and call your counter method from that.

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
    @Override
    void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // Your counter method
        updateCount();
    }
    @Override
    void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateCount();
    }
});
```